# get response from InvokeHTTP POST

Tags: apache-nifi

New to NiFi!

I'm using InvokeHTTP nifi processor (using this link as an example to implement my flow http://www.tomaszezula.com/2016/10/30/nifi-and-http-post-configuration/). I currently need to do POST in order to authenticate against a server I am using. I am able to POST successfully. However, I need to be able to get the data returned from the response of the POST that was executed. When I look at InvokeHTTPs output into the success queue all I see is the body which I had posted. Is there anyway for me to get the response into a flowfile?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Apache NiFi's [InvokeHTTP](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.2.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.InvokeHTTP/index.html) processor sends the response content to a separate relationship from the original flowfile.  You will want to separately route this `response` relationship.

[image: InvokeHTTP response relationship]

InvokeHTTP also has a `Put Response Body In Attribute` property, which you can set to capture the response as a attribute, rather than a separate flowfile.  This might be useful for an auth token.

Comment: Sorry I just have a related problem about this. How to set proper attribute name of it, Thank you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57760560/name-of-attribute-for-put-response-body-in-attribute-in-invokehttp