# Name of attribute for “Put Response Body In Attribute” in invokeHTTP

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a endpoint would return response as follow.

```
{
   "result": [
   {},
   ....
   {}]
}
```

I am trying to use invokeHTTP and enable  “Put Response Body In Attribute” to keep origin flowfile and response from api.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/HMpnBYx.png]

but it seems add a attribute named $.result as follow

[image]

Is there any way to set a proper name for result attribute ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to extract results using a JSON path. However this is not possible from within InvokeHttp. You may want to use [EvaluateJsonPath](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.EvaluateJsonPath/index.html) processor.

[Documentation for Put Response Body In Attribute](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.InvokeHTTP/index.html):

> If set, the response body received back will be put into an attribute
>   of the original FlowFile instead of a separate FlowFile. The attribute
>   key to put to is determined by evaluating value of this property.

To keep the original flow file after calling InvokeHttp, you can move it to an attribute (if the content is small enough) just before calling InvokeHttp or you can use MergeContent with original flow file and response flow file from InvokeHttp.